# Implementing voice control next / previous / pause / resume with audioPlayer

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I've built an audioPlayer Capsule that retrieves and plays a playlist of audio from a remote endpoint.

In the simulator and on my Galaxy s9, I can invoke the Capsule & play audio. I can also use the navigation controls to skip forward / go back.

However, in both the simulator & the device, `Next`, `Previous`, `Pause`, `Stop`, and `Resume` commands are all interpreted as `PlayPlaylist` Actions (which passes my playlist to `audioPlay.PlayAudio`) and simply start playing the audio from the beginning.

Do I need to hook into or build new Actions to manually trigger these audio control functions? I figured these would be "free" or built-in.

Additionally, I'm trying to figure out how to identify *which* AudioItem index I'm playing, so I can update the result view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voice command such as `play/stop/next/previous/resume` are built-in for audio player (not the library, but in marketplace itself).

Thus, developer at current stage has no control over the audio player once start player and has to rely on the voice command.

As a result:

1. Developer should **NOT** add training for these voice command.
2. There is no way to test the voice command in IDE or on-device testing, but rest assured that once your capsule released to marketplace these voice command would work.
3. You can check any of the **sleep sound** capsule in market place and verify the feature. None of them has training for voice command.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen that behavior.  Since you have an S9, you can confirm in the Bixby Market place with an existing capsule that's using the audio player.  For example, you can enable AudioBurst.  Start the audio player, then click on the Bixby button and and say similar commands like...

```
Next, Previous, Pause, etc
```

I was getting the expected behavior.  If you're not, it might be something related to your specific capsule.  Please confirm at your convenience.

Comment: Thanks Pete - I did try the AudioBurst Capsule, and that one was able to resume/pause/skip just fine. So it probably is something in code or related to not being certified yet. I'll reach out via email directly.

Comment: Consider also that the Category you choose for your Audio item will affect how the Audio Player is configured.  For example, setting the category to 'SINGLE' will only provide play/pause...while the 'PODCAST' category will allow for play/pause, previous, next, etc.  More info here:  https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/library.audio