# Conversation driver for next/previous for audio

Tags: bixby

Saw a post look similar to this question [Implementing voice control next / previous / pause / resume with audioPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57698698/implementing-voice-control-next-previous-pause-resume-with-audioplayer). Very unsure to ask about this, but, is there anyway or possible to add conversation drivers for result view which play an audio, that enable it to go for the next audio or previous audio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to implement **previous** or **next** as conversation drivers, as these are already built-in in Bixby marketplace. Please note IDE and on-device testing cannot confirm this behavior as it requires marketplace.

Try any podcast capsules in marketplace to verify the **next/previous** behavior in marketplace.

For users wish not use voice input, they can always use the media controller's normal pause/resume/previous/next button.